# Can TAFX recognise different colours on win form applications?

Tags: winforms, testing, automated-tests, tafx

I am looking into evaluating some GUI testing tools for project we are running and among others I downloaded Test Automation FX (TAFX), http://testautomationfx.com. Frontend of application under test is written using Windows forms.

Can the tool recognise different colours on win form applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by using property verification you can. E.g.

```
MainForm.VerifyProperty("BackColor", Color.Red);
```

There is an example available at the tafx features pages; [How To Accessing properties and methods in the AUT](http://www.testautomationfx.com/features/how-to/83-accessing-properties-and-methods-in-the-aut/index.html).